# 2 three.js canvas don't render simultaneously

Tags: three.js

I'm running 2 examples from three.js website. They work perfectly independently but when I stick them together in one page, only one of them work.

**Example 1**

```
    var SEPARATION = 100, AMOUNTX = 50, AMOUNTY = 50;
var container, stats;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var particles, particle, count = 0;
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
init();
animate();
function init() {
    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight , 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 1000;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    particles = new Array();
    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {
        color: 0xa50034,
        program: function ( context ) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
            context.fill();
        }
    } );
    var i = 0;
    for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {
        for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {
            particle = particles[ i ++ ] = new THREE.Sprite( material );
            particle.position.x = ix * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTX * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
            particle.position.z = iy * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTY * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
            scene.add( particle );
        }
    }
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 'white');
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight - 200 );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    stats = new Stats();
    container.appendChild( stats.dom );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );
    //
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}
function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
//
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
    mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
}
function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {
    if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
    }
}
function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {
    if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
    }
}
//
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    stats.update();
}
function render() {
    camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
    camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    var i = 0;
    for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {
        for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {
            particle = particles[ i++ ];
            particle.position.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) * 50 ) +
                    ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) * 50 );
            particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) + 1 ) * 4 +
                    ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) + 1 ) * 4;
        }
    }
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    count += 0.1;
}
```

**Example 2**

```
var Bird = function () {
    var scope = this;
    THREE.Geometry.call( this );
    v(   5,   0,   0 );
    v( - 5, - 2,   1 );
    v( - 5,   0,   0 );
    v( - 5, - 2, - 1 );
    v(   0,   2, - 6 );
    v(   0,   2,   6 );
    v(   2,   0,   0 );
    v( - 3,   0,   0 );
    f3( 0, 2, 1 );
    f3( 4, 7, 6 );
    f3( 5, 6, 7 );
    this.computeFaceNormals();
    function v( x, y, z ) {
        scope.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z ) );
    }
    function f3( a, b, c ) {
        scope.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( a, b, c ) );
    }
};

Bird.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Geometry.prototype );
Bird.prototype.constructor = Bird;
// Based on https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/6910
var Boid = function () {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(),
            _acceleration, _width = 500, _height = 500, _depth = 200, _goal, _neighborhoodRadius = 100,
            _maxSpeed = 4, _maxSteerForce = 0.1, _avoidWalls = false;
    this.position = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
    _acceleration = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.setGoal = function ( target ) {
        _goal = target;
    };
    this.setAvoidWalls = function ( value ) {
        _avoidWalls = value;
    };
    this.setWorldSize = function ( width, height, depth ) {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        _depth = depth;
    };
    this.run = function ( boids ) {
        if ( _avoidWalls ) {
            vector.set( - _width, this.position.y, this.position.z );
            vector = this.avoid( vector );
            vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
            _acceleration.add( vector );
            vector.set( _width, this.position.y, this.position.z );
            vector = this.avoid( vector );
            vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
            _acceleration.add( vector );
            vector.set( this.position.x, - _height, this.position.z );
            vector = this.avoid( vector );
            vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
            _acceleration.add( vector );
            vector.set( this.position.x, _height, this.position.z );
            vector = this.avoid( vector );
            vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
            _acceleration.add( vector );
            vector.set( this.position.x, this.position.y, - _depth );
            vector = this.avoid( vector );
            vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
            _acceleration.add( vector );
            vector.set( this.position.x, this.position.y, _depth );
            vector = this.avoid( vector );
            vector.multiplyScalar( 5 );
            _acceleration.add( vector );
        }/* else {
                    this.checkBounds();
                }
                */
        if ( Math.random() > 0.5 ) {
            this.flock( boids );
        }
        this.move();
    };
    this.flock = function ( boids ) {
        if ( _goal ) {
            _acceleration.add( this.reach( _goal, 0.005 ) );
        }
        _acceleration.add( this.alignment( boids ) );
        _acceleration.add( this.cohesion( boids ) );
        _acceleration.add( this.separation( boids ) );
    };
    this.move = function () {
        this.velocity.add( _acceleration );
        var l = this.velocity.length();
        if ( l > _maxSpeed ) {
            this.velocity.divideScalar( l / _maxSpeed );
        }
        this.position.add( this.velocity );
        _acceleration.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    };
    this.checkBounds = function () {
        if ( this.position.x >   _width ) this.position.x = - _width;
        if ( this.position.x < - _width ) this.position.x =   _width;
        if ( this.position.y >   _height ) this.position.y = - _height;
        if ( this.position.y < - _height ) this.position.y =  _height;
        if ( this.position.z >  _depth ) this.position.z = - _depth;
        if ( this.position.z < - _depth ) this.position.z =  _depth;
    };
    //
    this.avoid = function ( target ) {
        var steer = new THREE.Vector3();
        steer.copy( this.position );
        steer.sub( target );
        steer.multiplyScalar( 1 / this.position.distanceToSquared( target ) );
        return steer;
    };
    this.repulse = function ( target ) {
        var distance = this.position.distanceTo( target );
        if ( distance < 150 ) {
            var steer = new THREE.Vector3();
            steer.subVectors( this.position, target );
            steer.multiplyScalar( 0.5 / distance );
            _acceleration.add( steer );
        }
    };
    this.reach = function ( target, amount ) {
        var steer = new THREE.Vector3();
        steer.subVectors( target, this.position );
        steer.multiplyScalar( amount );
        return steer;
    };
    this.alignment = function ( boids ) {
        var count = 0;
        var velSum = new THREE.Vector3();
        for ( var i = 0, il = boids.length; i < il; i++ ) {
            if ( Math.random() > 0.6 ) continue;
            var boid = boids[ i ];
            var distance = boid.position.distanceTo( this.position );
            if ( distance > 0 && distance <= _neighborhoodRadius ) {
                velSum.add( boid.velocity );
                count++;
            }
        }
        if ( count > 0 ) {
            velSum.divideScalar( count );
            var l = velSum.length();
            if ( l > _maxSteerForce ) {
                velSum.divideScalar( l / _maxSteerForce );
            }
        }
        return velSum;
    };
    this.cohesion = function ( boids ) {
        var count = 0;
        var posSum = new THREE.Vector3();
        var steer = new THREE.Vector3();
        for ( var i = 0, il = boids.length; i < il; i ++ ) {
            if ( Math.random() > 0.6 ) continue;
            var boid = boids[ i ];
            var distance = boid.position.distanceTo( this.position );
            if ( distance > 0 && distance <= _neighborhoodRadius ) {
                posSum.add( boid.position );
                count++;
            }
        }
        if ( count > 0 ) {
            posSum.divideScalar( count );
        }
        steer.subVectors( posSum, this.position );
        var l = steer.length();
        if ( l > _maxSteerForce ) {
            steer.divideScalar( l / _maxSteerForce );
        }
        return steer;
    };
    this.separation = function ( boids ) {
        var posSum = new THREE.Vector3();
        var repulse = new THREE.Vector3();
        for ( var i = 0, il = boids.length; i < il; i ++ ) {
            if ( Math.random() > 0.6 ) continue;
            var boid = boids[ i ];
            var distance = boid.position.distanceTo( this.position );
            if ( distance > 0 && distance <= _neighborhoodRadius ) {
                repulse.subVectors( this.position, boid.position );
                repulse.normalize();
                repulse.divideScalar( distance );
                posSum.add( repulse );
            }
        }
        return posSum;
    };
};
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
        SCREEN_WIDTH_HALF = SCREEN_WIDTH  / 2,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT_HALF = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
var camera, scene, renderer,
        birds, bird;
var boid, boids;
var stats;
init();
animate();
function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 450;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 'white');
    birds = [];
    boids = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < 200; i ++ ) {
        boid = boids[ i ] = new Boid();
        boid.position.x = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
        boid.position.y = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
        boid.position.z = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
        boid.velocity.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        boid.velocity.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        boid.velocity.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        boid.setAvoidWalls( true );
        boid.setWorldSize( 500, 500, 400 );
        bird = birds[ i ] = new THREE.Mesh( new Bird(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:Math.random() * 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ) );
        bird.phase = Math.floor( Math.random() * 62.83 );
        scene.add( bird );
    }
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    stats = new Stats();
    document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild(stats.dom);
    //
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( event.clientX - SCREEN_WIDTH_HALF, - event.clientY + SCREEN_HEIGHT_HALF, 0 );
    for ( var i = 0, il = boids.length; i < il; i++ ) {
        boid = boids[ i ];
        vector.z = boid.position.z;
        boid.repulse( vector );
    }
}
//
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    stats.begin();
    render();
    stats.end();
}
function render() {
    for ( var i = 0, il = birds.length; i < il; i++ ) {
        boid = boids[ i ];
        boid.run( boids );
        bird = birds[ i ];
        bird.position.copy( boids[ i ].position );
        var color = bird.material.color;
        color.r = color.g = color.b = ( 500 - bird.position.z ) / 1000;
        bird.rotation.y = Math.atan2( - boid.velocity.z, boid.velocity.x );
        bird.rotation.z = Math.asin( boid.velocity.y / boid.velocity.length() );
        bird.phase = ( bird.phase + ( Math.max( 0, bird.rotation.z ) + 0.1 )  ) % 62.83;
        bird.geometry.vertices[ 5 ].y = bird.geometry.vertices[ 4 ].y = Math.sin( bird.phase ) * 5;
    }
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

Comment: What should we do with the parts of the question in Ancient Latin?

Comment: nothing, sorry about that, the system don't let me post a question which is mainly code claiming that more text should be added. So I did. Don't really have more to say regarding this question, just dont understand why I cannot render both of them in the same page. Some three.js feature that I still did not learn

Comment: maybe some functions or variables cannot be in duplicate, but i don't know which ones

Comment: Run your combined JavaScript code through a linter (like `eslint`). It will tell you if there are any obvious problems, like redefined functions/variables. Otherwise, please update the code in your question to be a minimal example that can replicate the issue you're seeing.